# check existence of a group of values in one column on the basis of value of another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Table `tbl_users` in MySQL database

[image]

How to check existence of a group of values in one column on the basis of a common value in another column.

Before executing SQL query "INSERT INTO `tbl_users` (`key`, `group-key`, `user-key`) VALUES (NULL, '24', '215'), (NULL, '24', '221'), (NULL, '24', '222');", I would like to check the existence of a group of `user-key`s (`215`, `221`, `222`) which associated with a common value in column `group-key`.

Comment: The data table is http://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Z2M.png.

Answer (score 0):

You can check something if exist before any insert operation occurs. Here is example code for doing that:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE city = 'London'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
     // row not found, do stuff...
} else {
    // do other stuff...
}
```

And the other method for solving this is to create a UNIQUE key on the fields you care about, and detect the integrity error after the fact.

Comment: I want to check a group of values in column `user-key`, here it is (215,221,222), which is already exists against `group-key` 18.